# Removing substring with parentheses at the end of string irrespectively of the content

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe is:

```
                           NameID
0   Mandalapu Harish (MH) (34567)
1             Roopa S (RS) (7861)
2  Geetha Harish (GH A) (9234178)
```

How could I remove those last set of parentheses using pandas?

```
                    Name
0  Mandalapu Harish (MH)
1           Roopa S (RS)
2   Geetha Harish (GH A)
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
df['Name'] = df['NameID'].str.replace(r'\s*\([^)]+\)$', '', regex=True)
```

*NB. if you want to remove the NameID column, use `df['Name'] = df.pop('NameID').str.replace(r'\s*\([^)]+\)$', '', regex=True)`.*

Output:

```
                           NameID                   Name
0   Mandalapu Harish (MH) (34567)  Mandalapu Harish (MH)
1             Roopa S (RS) (7861)           Roopa S (RS)
2  Geetha Harish (GH A) (9234178)   Geetha Harish (GH A)
```

Comment: Thank you mozway now I am getting my expected out put..

Comment: @MandalapuHarish you're welcome, next time please don't use images of data but **text** (see my edit to your question for a correct format)

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, which is based on [`pandas.Series.str.rsplit`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html):

```
df['NameID'].str.rsplit(n=1).str[0]
```

Output:

```
0    Mandalapu Harish (MH)
1             Roopa S (RS)
2     Geetha Harish (GH A)
Name: NameID, dtype: object
```